# SQL Error - #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1241

```
SELECT 
    k.*, 
    y.exchange,
        (
        SELECT 
            close AS close_20, 
            close_adj AS close_adj_20
            FROM stocks k
            WHERE 
                t = (
                    SELECT z.t
                    FROM usa_stocks_daily_bar z
                    WHERE 
                        t < k.t     
                    ORDER BY z.t DESC
                    LIMIT 20                                    
                    )
                AND id = k.id
            LIMIT 1     
        )
FROM stocks k
JOIN symbols y
    ON k.id = y.id
WHERE   
    (
    y.exchange = 'NASDAQ CM' OR
    y.exchange = 'NASDAQ GM'
    )
    AND k.t BETWEEN 20150101 AND 20150110
ORDER BY t ASC
```

Getting the error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Trying to merge these two queries together, to get the close from 20 days ago, but cannot get this query to work.

As the query runs down the table stocks k, the date to get the close_adj and close changes from -20 days ago.

Comment: You have a subquery in the `select` that returns two columns.  Of course this doesn't work.  A scalar subquery is expected there and only one column is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon mentioned, you have a subquery which is returning multiple values where MySQL is expecting a (single) scalar value.  One workaround would be to use `WHERE IN` in place of what you had:

```
WHERE t IN
(
    SELECT z.t
    FROM usa_stocks_daily_bar z
    WHERE t < k.t     
    ORDER BY z.t DESC
    LIMIT 20                                    
)
```